# Not getting all errors of row in a sequence - Laravel Excel

Tags: excel, laravel, validation, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel Excel to import data into database, all the things working fine but I am getting error when something happen unexpected and it returns like this

- There was an error on row 2. The gr field is required.
- There was an error on row 3. The gr field is required.
- There was an error on row 2. The place_of_birth field is required.
- There was an error on row 3. The place_of_birth field is required.

But I need this in a sequence according to rows not columns, like:

- There was an error on row 2. The gr field is required.
- There was an error on row 2. The place_of_birth field is required.
- There was an error on row 3. The gr field is required.
- There was an error on row 3. The place_of_birth field is required.

How can I modify my Rules:

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [ 
            '*.temporary_gr' =>  'required|unique:admissions,temporary_gr|string|min:1,max:10',
            '*.place_of_birth' =>  'required|alpha|max:30',                
            ]
}
```

Collection Method:

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $admisssion                         = new Admission();
            $admisssion->gr                     = $row["gr"];
            $admisssion->dob                    = $row["dob"];
            $admisssion->save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove `required` from the condition

`'*.temporary_gr' =>  'required|unique:admissions,temporary_gr|string|min:1,max:10',`.

it should look like this afterwards

`'*.temporary_gr' =>  'unique:admissions,temporary_gr|string|min:1,max:10',`

Comment: I tried this, but not getting my desired result.

Comment: @ArsalanAhmed did you check to see if the values are actually collected? that might be the problem

Comment: @fengo yes, I am getting values and my validator working fine but not return as I want.